# Using GWT Generators for custom annotations

Tags: java, gwt, annotations

How can i use GWT generator by annotations instead interface marker?

For example: i have a View with some ui fields, like Buttons and TextBoxes. Now i want to fields, which have annotation @Hide("true"), was hidden by "setVisible(false)" method.

Should i use annotation type instead interface in GWT module xml file? Or i have to generate all my View class, parse it, check annotations and generate new View with invoke setVisible(true) in constructor? Or maybe is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GWT generator is triggered by a type (passed to `GWT.create()`), so while it could be called by a matching annotation, that annotation would have to be on the type itself, not on a field. Also, and more importantly, that's not going to happen: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9172

IMO, you should use an annotation processor generating a helper class that calls `setVisible` on the appropriate fields, similar to how generated UiBinder sets the fields when its `generateAndBindUi` method is called. So you'd call UiBinder (if you use it), then call your generated helper class (or possibly have the helper class handle the UiBinder bit for you).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Looks like I won't be able to hide the presence of the helper class, and i will have to call it programmaticaly.

Comment: Technically, you could probably hide it: have a generator for UiBinder (assuming we're talking about it) that generates a new UiBinder interface also extending a marker interface with which the original UiBinder generator is bound, and a UiBinder implementation that `GWT.create()`s the generated interface and then calls the `setVisible` as needed. Too much "magic" to my taste, not worth it; but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Looking forward to GWT 3.0, I would advise you to write an annotation processor instead of a generator to do the job.

To give you an idea on how it works, you can take a look here:

https://github.com/FrankHossfeld/gwt-editor-apt

This is a small, not ready yet, proof of concept to replace the editor generator with an annotation processor.

Comment: Thanks for request and the link you provided. Look's like processor is need less extra-code, and it can intercept annotation directly. As i understand, it's invokes only from maven rather similar generators, which started during GWT compile?  Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You are right. annotation processor are invoked during the build process and not - as generators are - invoked during the GWT compile. But, the tools provided by the GWT generators are much more powerful than the one which comes with an annotation processor.