# Handling element attributes based on user roles in GWT

Tags: gwt, authorization

I am trying to tackle a quite common scenario in GWT based application.

> If user has role 'ROLE_A', then show him only 'Search' button. All the
>   other buttons will be disabled.

- One way to address this is by calling an async service to get the user's roles and then handle the visibility/accessibility of different UI components.
- Is there any generic way in GWT to address authorization? I referred to [Handle Authorization in GWT application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973628/handle-authorization-in-gwt-application) and [Using GWT Generators for custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146768/using-gwt-generators-for-custom-annotations) but couldn't get whatever I need.

I'm using `GWT 2.4.0` with `Spring 3.0.5`.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it (and I think how it should be done, really) is to include the roles [into the HTML host page](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html), rather than getting them through an additional request. Have a look at my [dagger-guice-rf-activities archetype](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) for an example (using Guice and Servlets security, but easily transposable to Spring)

Then on the client, use plain Java `if`s to handle the UI. And for those big parts of the app that only some users will see/use, use code splitting so other users don't have to download too much code.

Comment: I agree that it's better having it on the HTML host page.